# An android:nohistory flag being ignored

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-task

Here's the scenario:

1. User uses Activity#1 to schedule an alarm (using the the android `AlarmManager` service), and goes back to home screen. Activity#1 remains in stack.
2. `AlarmReciever`'s `onReceived()` is called as planned:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

      Intent intent = new Intent(context ,Activity2.class);

   intent.setFlags(
           Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
           Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
                   );

   context.startActivity(intent);
   }
   ```
3. Activity#2 (`Activity2`) starts successfully.

   ```
   public class Activity2 extends Activity {
     @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout_2);

       getWindow().addFlags(
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON |
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                       WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
       );

   }

   @Override
   protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();

       findViewById(R.id.dismiss_button).setOnClickListener(
               new View.OnClickListener() {
                   @Override
                   public void onClick(View v) {
                       finish();

                   }
               }
       );

   }
   ```

   }
4. User clicks a button (`R.id.dismiss_button`) to `finish()` Activity#2.
5. System moves back to homescreen as expected, **yet Activity#2 remains on stack** (it appears when the user clicks on [Recent Button](http://developer.android.com/design/handhelds/index.html#Recents%20screen))

Please notice that in addition to setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` flag for the intent, the flag was also specified in the `AndroidManifest.xml` (and I tried also each of them separably):

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:launchMode= "singleInstance"
        android:noHistory="true"
        >
    </activity>
```

Also, the flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is required as the Activity#2 being started from an `AlarmReceiver` rather than another activity.

Answer (score 4):

The NO_HISTORY flag just prevents this `Activity` from appearing in the task stack once the `Activity` is no longer visible. In your case, if you were to press HOME when `Activity2` is shown, you would see that Android calls `finish()` and `onDestroy()` on that activity right away (which isn't the usual behaviour when a task is put into the background).

To do what you want, you need to add

```
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

to the manifest entry for your `Activity`. This tells Android not to put your task in the list of recent tasks.

Comment: Wasn't aware of android:excludeFromRecents. Thanks.